# The selected stored procedure returns no columns, when i try to import my stored procedure inside my asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, edmx

I have the following stored procedure inside my SQL server 2008 r2 & asp.net mvc web application:

```
USE [ITSERres]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AdvanceSearchSP] 
/* Script Date: 08/04/2014 16:21:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AdvanceSearch2]    
/* Script Date: 07/18/2014 10:37:47 ******/


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdvanceSearchSP]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        
        @SearchType nvarchar(10) = null,
        @CustomerID bigint = null,
        @StringCustomerID nvarchar(50) = null,
        @SiteID bigint = null,
        @StateID bigint = null,
        @PrimarycustomerOnly bit = false,
        @RoleID int = null,
        @TypeID int = null,
        @IsManaged bit = null,
        @Name nvarchar(125) = null,
        @NameSelection nvarchar(10) = null,
        @Tag nvarchar(50) = null,
        @TagSelection nvarchar(10) =null,
        @ServiceTag nvarchar(100) = null,
        @ServiceTagSelection nvarchar(10) =null,
        @SerialNumber nvarchar(50) = null,
        @SerialNumberSelection nvarchar(10) =null,
        @Comment nvarchar(250) = null,
        @CommentSelection nvarchar(10) =null,
        @IP nvarchar(50) = null,
        @IPSelection nvarchar(10) = null,
         @MAC nvarchar(50) = null,
         @MACSelection nvarchar(10) = null
    AS
    BEGIN
      
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
if(@SearchType = 'name')
Begin 
        -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT t.Tag , r.RESOURCENAME , rs.DISPLAYSTATE AS StateName,
        tt.Name AS TypeName ,
        sdo.NAME AS sitename ,
        accountdef.ORG_NAME AS cusotmername,
        t.IsManaged AS ismanaged ,
        sysinfo.SERVICETAG,r.SERIALNO
  //code goes here...
```

I did the following:-

1. I mapped the SP inside my .edmx file.
2. I right-click on the .edmx file, and click on "Model Browser".
3. Under my Model, I click on function Import.
4. I right-click on the SP, and click on edit.
   then when I click on "Get Column Info", I got the following message:-

> The selected stored procedure returns no columns

so can anyone advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 28):

I also face the same problem. Just FYI, my stored procedures contains Temporary Tables.
After googling a bit, found this page that solved my problem :

http://forums.asp.net/t/2000731.aspx?EF+4+0+The+selected+stored+procedure+returns+no+columns+when+i+try+to+import+my+stored+procedure+inside+my+asp+net+mvc

The solution suggested is to add SET FMTONLY OFF in the beginning of the stored procedure 
and it is working perfectly for my case.

maybe you can have a try on it.

Comment: This works, but in my case I had to find the function in the model browser, then click the return type , then manually update the 'get column information' there. Running update model from db didn't help.

Comment: Awesome, you saved me a lot of trouble! Worked for me  :)

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same issue, but in my case it turned out to be my database connection string that was using a user with limited permissions. 
I assume that EF is not able to work out the schema structure without a certain level of rights for the connection being used.

I changed my connection string to a user with higher permissions, updated my EDMX, and then changed back to the lower level user.

This is not ideal, but I guess I could investigate to see exactly what permissions EF needs, and then consider whether these are rights I am willing to grant my general access user. (One for another day)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
create proc sp_ExecuteTest
@IdMachines nvarchar(50)
as
SET FMTONLY OFF;
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
CREATE table #tempTable(IdMachine int)
SET @SQLQuery = 'insert into #tempTable select IdMachine from MachineMaster where idmachine IN(' + @IdMachines + ')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery
SELECT * FROM #tempTable
drop table #tempTable
```

Comment: Try this... what exactly?